# MySQL stored procedure that accepts string with multiple values in parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want best way to call store procedure where i have multiple values in single parameter like City parameter having values like 'london','lyon','kln' and many more.

My stored procedure is like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetCityEmpData`(IN `City` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN 
   SELECT * FROM Employees 
   WHERE Employees.City in (City);
END
```

and call it like this

```
call GetCityEmpData("'London',Lyon'") ;
```

it returns 0 rows where there is data for the given parameters.
Is it possible to execute the same without prepare statement?

Comment: here when you pass argument to procedure "'London',Lyon'" its take whole string not commas seprated, thats why its 0 rows.

Comment: Is there any solution to resolve it?

Comment: If i remove double quotes then it will take as 2 parameters and throws error.

Comment: you should remove it in procedure not calling time

Comment: i haven't given any double quotes in procedure. Could you please suggest example according to my question?

Comment: i have given answer. you can use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetCityEmpData`(`City` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
   set @query = concat("SELECT * FROM Employees 
                        WHERE Employees.City in (" , City , ")");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt ;
END
```

then you can call your procedure as you wanted :

```
call GetCityEmpData("'London','Lyon'") ;
```

Comment: Is this the only way to execute the stored procedure? Please suggest any other solution for this.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this. I just want to know is there any alternative?

Comment: This solution is working for me, but in a few seconds it is throwing the following error "Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." Any help how to get around this.

Comment: This solution is prone to SQL injection use with better care :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using find_in_set method

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetCityEmpData`(IN `City` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN 
   SELECT * FROM Employees 
   WHERE FIND_IN_SET (Employees.City ,City);
END
```

and call it like

```
call GetCityEmpData('London,Lyon');
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Building SQL dynamically is asking for trouble.

Comment: Building SQL dynamically is not that bad if we write parameterized query.

But after writing  it using concat method I find my hands dirty :)